# build perfect swift server side development No account for a team "ABCDEFGH"

Tags: swift, perfect, swift5

I'm trying to create a web api using Swift Perfect. Every time I build the project file, my team name was changing to this ABCDEFGH name. For each and every dependency again I need to change the developer team name. After execute `swift package generate-xcodeproj` All certificates also I added.

is there any way to resolve this? please help me!

````
 No account for team "ABCDEFGHIJ".
 Add a new account in the Accounts preference pane or verify that your accounts have valid credentials.```
````

Comment: Open your xyz.xcodeproj file. 
goto Signing and capability.
uncheck automatically manage signing or change your team name. 

Now clean build. after that it will work fine. its working for me in web development using Swift Perfect